# Schema.org breadcrumbs with entry linking to a non-existing page (which redirects to the homepage)?

Tags: schema.org, breadcrumbs, rich-snippets

I am trying to organize my SERP and I want my site to display like this on SERP:

> www.example.com > services > repair

But the problem is the "services" URL doesnt exist but 301 redirected to homepage.

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http:\/\/schema.org",
    "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
    "itemListElement": [{
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 1,
        "item": {
            "@id": "\/services\/",
            "name": "Services"
        }
    },
    {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 2,
        "item": {
            "@id": "\/repair\/",
            "name": "Repair"
        }
    }]
}
```

Will the above code work?

Comment: It’s not really feasible to answer this for all search engines. Furthermore, for this question to be on-topic here, it can only ask about the published documentation for it, not if it will actually work in practice (in case it’s not documented). For more SEO-related topics, you might want to let it get migrated to [webmasters.se].

Comment: ok before i posted the question i searched for related question and all questions where asked in this site, i will migrate to the site you referred, thanks